# Locating cloudwatch error log based on serverless error information

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless

I've got a serverless error and I think I should be able to find the cloudwatch log mentioned solely based on the information in the error but I'm finding it difficult to locate.

*ServerlessError: An error occurred: PreSignUpTriggerCustomCognitoUserPool1 - Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Cannot read property 'Id' of null See details in CloudWatch Log: 2021/09/27/[$LATEST]730e87607dda45b9addb72bf7d78a60d (RequestId: b44d00d0-9c24-43b8-b694-f3f709320db4).*

Everything I find says to first go into the associated log group and I don't know which log group this guy would be under... So I went through each and every log group and couldn't find the referenced log stream `2021/09/27/[$LATEST]730e87607dda45b9addb72bf7d78a60d`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to go to the Lambda service page, locate the `PreSignUpTriggerCustomCognitoUserPool1` lambda, go to the monitoring tab and there should be able to go to the correct log group directly.